# Magento: Special Product with price input field

Tags: magento-1.9, product, template, frontend, zend-framework

I have a lot of standard products in my magento.

Now i need a special kind of products. Everythink is the same like a stanard product, only hidden price.

Every special product have this formular:

```
Price: The customer can type the price in the field
URL: The customer can type the URL in the field
Size: The customer can type the size in the field
Color: The customer can type the color in the field
```

My idea is to use a template for this special kind of products.
Do you have any ideas how i can get this special kind of products?

Answer (score 0):

I have another idea.Because all you need is hidden price for that specific product, why do you just :

1/ Create a new custom attribute for example : Hide price (attribute code = hide_price)-  "select : yes-no" and add it to your product. (http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-create-an-attribute-and-apply-it-to-products.html)

Remeber to set "hide price" field is **"Visible on Catalog Pages on Front-end" = Yes.**

2/ Adjust price in template based on the value yes or no of Hidden price field:

Find the price template in your theme : catalog/product/price.phtml and edit it :

```
if ( ! $_product->getHidePrice()) { **// only hide_price = no => show price**

   echo $_coreHelper->formatPrice($_price, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see one problem in your solution.

The price is not mapped to the price attribute in the order.
I found this solution to mapp the custom price to the magento price attribute:

http://www.mageworx.com/custom-price-magento-extension.html
Then i create a custom Template for my product. I do this in the "Custom Layout Update" product tab.

I will check my work in the next days and send you report.